# In Pandas, how can I replace an empty list?

Tags: python, google-maps, pandas, gis, geocoding

In my pandas dataframe, I have one column which contains lists. Every now and then, the list is empty. I want to replace the values which are an empty list with either NULL or [0,0]. Below is the pandas series containing these lists.

```
latlng = [[51.8927954, 0.9488230999999999], 
          [51.6207569, 0.1837936], 
          [50.8527375, -1.07789], 
          [], 
          [51.6216562, 0.119973], 
          [51.5368817, -0.1753158], 
          [51.9144871, -0.1612784], 
          [], 
          [51.5323296, -0.1771649], 
          [54.0873327, -1.3961415]]
```

The problem is that I want to separate these coordinates into lat & long columns - however, if I use latlng[1], it will be outside of the index for the empty list.

I've tried replacing the empty list [] with [0,0] however I'm receiving an Error saying I'm trying to replace 1 piece of data with 2.

```
df['latlng'].replace([[]], [0,0])
```

How can I replace the empty lists in my column with either NULL or [0,0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: if the goal is to separate latitude and longitude into two columns, this should work directly:

```
df['lat'] = df['latlng'].str[0]
df['lng'] = df['latlng'].str[1]
```

Slicing will return `NaN` for empty lists. To get `0` instead, use `fillna`:

```
df['lat'] = df['latlng'].str[0].fillna(0)
df['lng'] = df['latlng'].str[1].fillna(0)
```

---

**Original answer**

Try the `str` accessor, which can be used for lists:

```
df['latlng'] = df['latlng'].where(df['latlng'].str.len() > 0, np.nan)
```

The `where` method keeps the original values where the condition is true, and replaces with the supplied value when not.

Comment: ValueError: Length of replacements must equal series length
I'm getting this error.

Comment: argh yes, it thinks `[0,0]` is an iterable of length 2, can you do with `np.nan` instead? (see my edit)

Comment: That has worked, yes, so any empty list is filled with NaN. Now, how would I create new columns for latlng[0] & latlng[1]? Would it ignore the value NaN?

Comment: Sorry I lost sight of your ultimate goal. Please see my edit for a direct answer to your question.

Comment: Just used your edit... And it works! Thanks so much, this has been bugging me for a day!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `apply`

```
In [439]: df['latlng'].apply(lambda x: x if x else [0, 0])
Out[439]:
0     [51.8927954, 0.9488231]
1     [51.6207569, 0.1837936]
2      [50.8527375, -1.07789]
3                      [0, 0]
4      [51.6216562, 0.119973]
5    [51.5368817, -0.1753158]
6    [51.9144871, -0.1612784]
7                      [0, 0]
8    [51.5323296, -0.1771649]
9    [54.0873327, -1.3961415]
Name: latlng, dtype: object
```